# localhost:3000/admin working but after hosting websiteurl/admin is not working

Tags: reactjs

firebase deployed app is working but in localhost:3000/admin it is moving to that route but after hosting its saying page not found when i search for websitename/admin
its is going to websitename/admin on button click but if i use direct url https://websitename/admin.web.app to move its showing 404 html page

this is my code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Quizzes from './components/Admin/Quizzes'
import AddNewQuiz from './components/Admin/AddNewQuiz'
import AddQuestion from './components/Admin/AddQuestion'
import EditQuiz from './components/Admin/EditQuiz'
import ViewResults from './components/Admin/ViewResults'
import UQuizzes from './components/User/Quizzes'
import ViewQuizDetails from './components/User/ViewQuizDetails'
import QuizCard from './components/User/QuizCard'
import LeaderBoard from './components/User/LeaderBoard'
import AttemptedQuizzes from './components/User/AttemptedQuizzes'

import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (

    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/">
          <div className="App">
            <UQuizzes />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/quizcard">
          <div className="App">
            <QuizCard />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/attemptedquizzes">
          <div className="App">
            <AttemptedQuizzes />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/leaderboard">
          <div className="App">
            <LeaderBoard />
          </div>
        </Route>

        <Route exact={true} path="/quizdetails">
          <div className="App">
            <ViewQuizDetails />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/admin">
          <div className="App">
            <Quizzes />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/addnewquiz">
          <div className="App">
            <AddNewQuiz />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/createquestion">
          <div className="App">
            <AddQuestion />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/editquiz/:fromAdd">
          <div className="App">
            <EditQuiz />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact={true} path="/results">
          <div className="App">
            <ViewResults />
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Problem is not clear

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using React app as Single Page Application. And since you are using it as Single Page Application, you must configure your host to handle the URL re-writing. (Meaning every request must forward to index.html) You can find the configuration here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```